# Matrix equation / Rewrite formula

Tags: matrices

I´m looking for a solution for matrix **W**.
Can anyone help me pls?

$$\mathbf W \cdot A =\mathbf W + A$$

$$A = 
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 3 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)$$

My solution:
**W** = $\left(\frac{A}{A-1}\right)$
Is this correct? 
Because $A-1$ is not possible - in my opinion (I thought you can´t subtract an integer from a matrix)

Comment: How do you divide by a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  If $\mathbf{W}A = \mathbf{W} + A$, then
$$
    \mathbf{W}(A-I) = A
$$
where $I$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.  Then
$$
    \mathbf{W} = A(A-I)^{-1}
$$
if $A-I$ is invertible.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: So my solution is now:

$$W = 
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    3 & -1 \\
    -1 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)$$